# Efficiency between using a string as a table key and splitting it into two tables

Tags: sql, relational-database

I'm contemplating efficiency using a string as a key in a database table. I have an abstract class called Command in my application that has a command key hard coded into the derived class such as "CREATE_ADMIN_USER" or "DELETE_NEWS_POST".

There is some configuration I would like to store in a database such as which roles can execute those commands.

What would be more efficient:

```
CommandKey        | Role
--------------------------
CREATE_ADMIN_USER | GodUser
DELETE_NEWS_POST  | Admin
DELETE_NEWS_POST  | Editor
```

OR

```
ID| CommandKey
--------------------------
1 | CREATE_ADMIN_USER
2 | DELETE_NEWS_POST

ID | Role
--------------------------
1  | GodUser
2  | Admin
3  | Editor

CommandKeyID | RoleId
---------------------
1            | 1
2            | 2
2            | 3
```

In the case of the first one, the downfall is that you have to store more characters for the command key string. This could become a space problem if you have 1000's of commands and multiple roles for many of them.

The downfall of the second one is that you have to create the join between the 3 tables.

Which one would be preferable between the two (if there is actually a preferable way): use more space OR join 3 tables.

Comment: In your second example, how do you plan to join those two tables? Another joining table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins on the primary key of a table are usually fairly cheap.  So I would expect the second alternative to be more efficient in most DBMSs, but since you haven't specified what DBMS you're using, it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Also, I believe that the second alternative is far more commonly used, for whatever reason.  And I can definitively say is that the second option will be far more manageable in the event that you decide to change the name of a role, or the string of a command key.

For all these reasons, I recommend the second option.